# Expanded Height of a Container in a Row to 100%

Tags: flutter

I have Row Widget in the Flutter:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text(description),
    Container(width: 5.0, color: Colors.orange,),
  ]
);
```

I want the Container to get expanded to a maximum height.

I cannot use CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, because I am not using a fixed height for Row (Reason is text can be one line, or it can take upto 10 lines). I don't want to use IntrinsicHeight because it causes performance issues.

Comment: Is it that maximum height a fixed value or do you want the contained to expand to cover all the available vertical space?

Answer (score 0):

Container is already an expanded widget if you are using it without using "height" property of it. it will automatically adjust the height according to content of it's child. or Just wrap the container with flexible, or use this package from pub.dev **readmore** I answered this but I think you were asking something different you can do a comment I'll come to you

Answer (score 0):

```
  Row(
  children: [
    Text(description),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

By wrapping the Container with Expanded, it will expand to fill the available space within the Row. This approach ensures that the Container expands vertically to the maximum height without explicitly setting a fixed height or using CrossAxisAlignment.stretch or IntrinsicHeight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Container to expand to the maximum height available within the Row without setting a fixed height for the Row, you can achieve this by wrapping it with an Expanded widget .

```
    Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'text',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            
            child: Container(
              width: 5.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Container widget with **Expanded** in order for the widget to take up all the remaining space.

```
Row(
    children: [
       Text(description),
       Expanded(
         child: Container(
                  width: 5.0, 
                  color: Colors.orange,
         ),
       ),
  ],
);
```